# Failed to compile REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Был полностью рабочий проект, однако, после того, как я переместил одну из папок, все сломалось. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: верните папку на место

Comment: Могу предположить: Когда вы изменили папку, вы не тронули импорты, т.е пути стали другими, а в таких случаях парой алиасы не спасают. Еще как вариант вы тронули что-то, что по правилам зарезервировано и такое лучше не изменять местами.

Comment: Посмотри на импорт `PostService` во второй строке, осознай, замени в его пути `./` на `../` :)